# 2 simultaneous rotate actions

Tags: rotation, sprite, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Is there a way to run 2 rotate actions on a sprite at the same time? I have a boat sprite and an oar sprite on the screen, and the oar sprite naturally rotates back and forth. I used a repeat forever action with a sequence of actions to have the oar sprite rotate back and forth through a 90 degree range. I then allow the user to rotate the boat.

I want the oar to continue its own rotation but also to rotate with the boat so that the oar doesn't look misplaced. When I have the boat rotate I create another action to rotate the oar even more and then it doesn't work. The oar just continues with its original action. Any help would be appreciated.

```
RotateBy * r11 = RotateBy::create(1.95f, 90);
RotateBy * r12 = RotateBy::create(1.95f, -90);

Sequence * s1 = Sequence::create(r11, r12, NULL);

RepeatForever * r1 = RepeatForever::create(s1);

oarSprite->runAction(r1);
```

Later on I have this in another method:

```
RotateBy * r = RotateBy::create(.1, boatSprite->getRotation());
```

The purpose of the last RotateBy action is to get the oar to rotate in relation to the boat.

Comment: Unclear what you done and what you need exactly. show some code if possible.

Comment: you could have simultaneous actions but from your question you are not clearing your point so its better you show some code to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the oar child of the boat. So oar will rotate with boat rotate action and the oars own.

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry, I didn't know you could add sprites to other sprites. Thanks.